# How can I add a callback to the .apply() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

In my code, I have an array of function calls. I loop over these calls and use .apply() to call them. The problem is that if the call of the new function takes any sort of time, the loop will .apply() and call the next function before the prior function is finished. >.< Here is an example:

```
function someFunc(element, calls){
  if(calls.length){
    fn = calls[0];
    calls.shift();
    fn.apply(element, args);
    someFunc(element, calls);
  }
}
```

So if there was a callback on the apply function then this could work how I want it to. i.e.

```
function someFunc(element, calls){
  if(calls.length){
    fn = calls[0];
    calls.shift();
    fn.apply(element, args, function(){
      someFunc(element, calls);
    });
  }
}
```

I also have a question about calling someFunc inside of a callback function. The functions in my `calls` array affect my `element` variable. So I want to make sure after it gets changed that it gets passed to someFunc in the callback so the next function can manipulate it as well. Sometimes I just get confused with the `this` context. :)

If it helps, I am using jQuery. I know how to add callbacks to jQuery methods but I don't know how to do that when I'm dealing with native JavaScript code. **How can I add a callback to the .apply() method?**

Comment: There's no way to do what you want unless you know a parameter pattern that all your functions follow.

Comment: @Pointy - Why would I need a parameter pattern if I put all of my parameters in an array aka `args`?

Comment: The problem is that there's no way to tell whether a function is asynchronous and designed to accept a callback function parameter (or two such parameters, or more). You can't make the system "wait" for a function and its asynchronous follow-on to finish.  Thus, if you *know* that your functions all (for example) take a callback as the last parameter, then you could work something out.

Comment: @Pointy if the called function adheres to a common interface (e.g. Promise) then you _can_ make the system "wait" for the async call to finish.

Comment: what sort of things can happen to `element`?  Just changes to its properties, or perhaps replacing it with a whole new object?

Comment: @Alnitak - As of now, just changes. But I plan on being able to replace it completely.

Comment: @Aust OK, see my updated answer.  In this version the element can be replaced with a new variable by each function in the chain.

Comment: @Alnitak well yes that's exactly what I meant :-)

Comment: @Pointy not exactly, I think - the promise is a requirement on the _return_ value of the function, not the pattern of parameters supplied to it.

Comment: Well @Alnitak knowing that the functions return a promise is, for the purpose of this question, the same sort of structural "knowledge" about the functions that's required to make it work.  My original point was that if the functions are just random things passed in from outer space, there's really nothing you can do.

Comment: @Alnitak your suggestion is a really good one however as it's somewhat more general and doesn't require the same kind of API change for the functions involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that every function you call returns a `promise`.  You can then "wait" for that promise to be "resolved" before continuing with the next function in your list:

```
function someFunc(element, calls) {
    if (calls.length) {
        var fn = calls.shift();
        fn.apply(element, args).done(function(el) {  // what's args?
            el = el || element;   // default to previous element if necessary
            someFunc(el, calls);
        });
    }
}
```

with each function looking something like:

```
function myFunc1(el) {
    var def = $.Deferred();

    // do something async, and "resolve" the deferred object in the async callback
    ...(function() {
        def.resolve(el);  // this "el" will get passed to the next function
    });

    return def.promise();
}
```

If the asynchronous task is an AJAX call you can just return the `jqXHR` result of `$.ajax` directly instead of creating a new deferred object.

Comment: If some of the functions I pass into my `calls` variable are not mine, how would I add the `$.Deferred()` object? Could I wrap it in another function, or is that even possible?

Comment: Yes, you could wrap the functions, but _somehow_ you still have to `resolve` the promise and that has to be done in the async callback.

Comment: So even if I wrapped it, I come back to the original problem that @Pointy brought up? Which is, if a function doesn't already have a callback, then what I want is impossible?

Comment: @Aust I've never yet seen an asynchronous function that _didn't_ have a "completion callback"...  They'd be kinda pointless without one.  Have you got an example?

Comment: Yes I didn't think of that. I was just trying to understand. :)